# How to view community wiki posts for a particular tag?

Tags: support, community-wiki, search, tag-search

Is there a way to view all the posts filed as community wiki for a particular tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Search for `[tag] wiki:yes`

For e.g. [`[python] wiki:yes`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D%20wiki:yes)